# XSD date format required

Tags: java, .net, xml, xsd

In XSD i want to validate date format in MM/DD/YYYY using regex.
Currently i am using following syntax which give me output in YYYY-DD-MM.

```
<xs:simpleType name="dateVal"> <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> <xs:pattern value="(19|20)((([02468][48]|[13579][26])-0?2-29)|\d\d-((0?[469]|11)-([012]?\d|3‌​0)|(l)-([012]?\d|3[01])|(0?2-([01]?\d|2[0-8]))))"></xs:pattern> </xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType>
```

Can any one help me to correct it for MM/DD/YYYY.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: <xs:simpleType name="dateVal">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="(19|20)((([02468][48]|[13579][26])-0?2-29)|\d\d-((0?[469]|11)-([012]?\d|30)|(l)-([012]?\d|3[01])|(0?2-([01]?\d|2[0-8]))))"></xs:pattern>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Date">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:pattern value="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: i want to validation for below. 1)Non Accepted values :02/29/2014 ,02/31/2014,04/31/2014 2)Accepted values 02/29/2016 (leap year).

Comment: @user964698:- I have updated my answer. Please check!

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern will match on the date format MM/DD/YYYY.

```
^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```

Working example [here](http://regexr.com/399hk).

As pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work as an XSD pattern.
Removing the anchors and incorrect escaping of `/` characters result in:

```
([0]\d|[1][0-2])/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?
```

Also, take a look at this: [Regular Expression Matching a Valid Date](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

Comment: it does not work.can you please modify it and give me.

Comment: In that example whatever values i m putting its accepting. Could you please give me in the xml formate i had posted earlier in this question.

Comment: If you input a valid MM/DD/YYYY to the example I provided, you get "1 match" in the top right corner of RegexR, and the text becomes blue. It does work-

Comment: <xs:simpleType name="dateVal">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$"></xs:pattern>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType> Try to run with this.And tell me its incorrect.

Comment: Exactly how it works within the XSD I cannot tell, but the regex does match any valid date in the format you asked for. If there is a specific problem while using it in the XSD, I cannot help I'm afraid.

Comment: Regex patterns in XSD are implicitly anchored. They should not contain ^ and $. Also they should not escape characters such as "/" which are not metacharacters.